# interact_plot on binary IV and continuous moderator

Tags: r, lm, interaction

Here are my variables:

- X: binary variable
- Y: continuous variable (min 3, max 21)
- M: continuous variable (min 2, max 14)

I have 60 participants in total (30 in each binary X). I want to see if M has any moderating effects on X and Y. I dummy coded X into 0 and 1 after changing it into a factor (as.factor). I then ran an lm() in R with interaction (X*M) and all main effects and interaction were significant as seen below.
[image]

I would now like to plot this and I'm trying to use interact_plot from the interactions package. Here is my code:

```
interact_plot(model = reg, pred = IncOrExc, modx = PerRisk)
```

But I get the following error message

```
Focal predictor ("pred") cannot be a factor. Either use it as modx, convert it to a numeric dummy variable
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm quite late but...
Interact_plot plots a continuous predictor variable on a continuous outcome. The moderator is the one that can be continuous or a factor. From your example, IncOrExc is the one you transform into a factor, right? So interact_plot is telling you that you should change it to a continuous predictor variable in order to plot it.